# Looking for the title of a short (~100 page) Herbert Simon book about "Bread-bricks"

Tags: mathematical-economics, theory, reference-request, simulations

I'm trying to find a short (~100 page) book by Herbert A. Simon in which he presents a simplified economics in which there is only one item of value and it is called the 'Bread-brick'. One can eat a breadbrick, or sell it, or store it, etc. He uses this simple world to illustrate certain topics in the study of economics. I have been looking for it for ages, and I don't know the title. I've googled endlessly, and perused all Simons books on google reader but I have come to nothing.

Comment: I was under the impression it was "bread bricks" too after watching a Marvin Minsky video

Answer (score 4):

It is my impression that it is "**bean-bricks**" and it is not a book but a paper/essay under the title **"The long-range economic effects of automation"**, which was included in the book

[HERBERT, A. S. (1965). The Shape of Automation for Men and Management.](http://HERBERT,%20A.%20S.%20(1965).%20The%20Shape%20of%20Automation%20for%20Men%20and%20Management.)

Go to the [on-line digital library of Carnegie Mellon University](http://digitalcollections.library.cmu.edu/portal/index.jsp)

and enter in the search "The Economic Effects of Automation" (without the "long-range" part). It (freely) downloads what appears to be a first version of the work (20 pages). The file may appear to not be a .pdf one, but I opened it with .pdf software alright.

At the end of page 9 Simon writes:

> *"In our hypothetical economy, only a single commodity, which we shall call **beanbricks**, is produced. Beanbricks serve both as the sole
>   consumption good (they are eaten), and as the sole form of capital
>   (they are burned as fuel used in producing more beanbricks). The other
>   productive resource in the economy, besides beanbricks, is labor".*

It does look like it is the first time Simon uses the term (the file is a scanned copy of Simon's manuscript).

**P.S:** Note that standard economic models of growth essentially assume exactly the same framework, since output is costlessly transformed into capital or becomes consumption.